# Why do quantum effects of particles dominate when the thermal de Broglie wavelength becomes comparable to the inter-particle spacing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-statistics

Why do quantum effects of particles dominate when the thermal de Broglie wavelength becomes comparable to the inter-particle spacing?

Comment: Effectively, its because of the Heisenberg uncertainty principal. Also, what do you mean by the _thermal_ de Broglie wavelength?

Comment: @Hanting Zhang It is probably a sentence from a book or a lecture.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305837/why-does-the-ratio-between-debroglie-wavelength-and-average-separation-the-size

Comment: I've copied my answer to your earlier version of this question, and voted to close this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As was stated in the comments, this can be related to the uncertainty principle. The essentials are given on the [thermal de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength) Wikipedia page, but I'll try to give a little more detail.

We define a "typical" atomic momentum at temperature $T$ as
$$
p_{\text{th}} = \sqrt{2\pi mk_BT}
$$ 
where $m$ is the atomic mass, and $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant.
This is approximately equal to the root-mean-square value of 
any component of the momentum, say $p_x$,
calculated from the classical statistical mechanics result (equipartition of energy) as
$$
\langle p_x^2\rangle = m k_B T
$$
In this kind of argument, numerical factors such as $\sqrt{2\pi}$ are not important.

From this, using de Broglie's relation, we can define a typical thermal wavelength of atoms
$$
\lambda_{\text{th}} = \frac{h}{p_{\text{th}}} = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2\pi mk_BT}}
$$
where $h$ is Planck's constant.
This is the main quantity of interest here.

This also serves as an estimate of the *uncertainty* in the atom's position. We expect most atoms to have a momentum in the range
$-p_{\text{th}}\ldots+p_{\text{th}}$,
so we roughly set $\Delta p\approx p_{\text{th}}$
and the uncertainty principle gives us
$$
\Delta x \approx \frac{\hbar/2}{\Delta p} \approx \lambda_{\text{th}}
$$
where again we don't worry too much about numerical factors.

Then, if we had a one-dimensional system of $N$ atoms on a line of length $L$, so the typical separation between atoms is $d=L/N$,
we would expect to be able to neglect quantum mechanical effects provided $\Delta x \ll d$, i.e. $\lambda_{\text{th}} \ll d$.
The atoms could be treated as points,
not significantly spread out by quantum mechanics.
A similar argument in 3D leads to the condition 
$\lambda_{\text{th}}^3 \ll V/N$
or $N\lambda_{\text{th}}^3/V \ll 1$.
So this is the "hand-waving" answer to your question.

It is possible to take this further, and this is done in statistical mechanical textbooks such as *Statistical Mechanics and Applications in Condensed Matter* by C Di Castro and R Raimondi. It's a bit of work (see their chapter 7), but the equation of state for an ideal gas obeying Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein statistics can be expressed, in the regime where the classical description is just starting to break down, as an expansion
$$
\frac{PV}{Nk_BT} = 1 \pm \frac{1}{2^{5/2}} \left(\frac{N\lambda_{\text{th}}^3}{V}\right)
+ \ldots
$$
and the crucial ratio appears as the first-order correction term
with a sign corresponding to whichever statistics applies, FD or BE.